# apply a method on a lazy stream with parallelism limit

Tags: java, scala

I have an iterator in scala:

```
val collections: Iterator[Callable[Boolean]] = ...
```

I would like to apply something to every element of that iterator with a constraint on the number of concurrent execution. I used the following implementation with a java thread pool (used another SO example):

```
val javaExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberThreads) // fixed thread pool
val scalaExecutor = JavaConversions.asExecutionContext(javaExecutor) //convert to scala executor
val futures: util.List[Future[Boolean]] = scalaExecutor.invokeAll(asJavaCollection(collections.toIterable)) // run pool, first convert Seq to java.util.Collection
// Here you have to be sure, that all task run
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
concurrent.Future(javaExecutor.shutdown()) // shutdown in new thread
val count = futures.map(future => Try(future.get)).count(_.isFailure)
```

The problem here is that it seems the underlying implementation is putting all callables in a queue so all the data loaded into memory causing `OutOfMemory`. I am looking for a way to implement that lazily, means not have all the callable in memory at once at any point of time.

Comment: Have you tried `Future.traverse` or `Future.fold`? Also, I think it's not the underlying implementation, but `collections.toIterable`, which loads the callables into memory.

Comment: You could consider using Akka Streams; it provides facilities to do async processing with explicitly limited parallelism, see e.g. http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.4/akka/stream/javadsl/Flow.html#mapAsync[T](parallelism:Int,f:akka.japi.function.Function[Out,java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[T]]):akka.stream.javadsl.Flow[In,T,Mat].